# Why can python files be modified while open in IDLE editor?

Tags: python, operating-system, python-module

When a .py file is being edited in IDLE, it can be renamed or deleted while still being able to run, but in other file types such as word files this is not allowed. You can even create a script using the os module to delete itself and then do an action, and that action still works. How is this possible?

Comment: The python interpreter reads the whole module into memory at import time. After that, subsequent changes on disk are not read unless a `reload` is called.

Answer (score 0):

When you run python scripts you scripts were loaded into memory. So you can edit your script files.